# Grunge Audio Effect in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, core-audio, audiokit

in the [smlue song](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smule.singandroid) app there is a effect named Grunge . 
  it makes song like old radio sounds . this is an screenshot from the app:
  [image]

as you can see there are also other effects there . 
  so how we can add those effects to our audios
  i already found a great library named [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) but i dont know how to to that with it

Comment: question is too broad. what have you tried?

Comment: there are similar steps for common 'vinyl effect' :
* Convert to mono.
* Add white noise.
* Bandpass. I would start with a HP at 80 HZ and a steep LP at 8 kHz, but that's a guess. You'll have to use your ears until it sounds like the gramophone. You should try Chebychev and Butterworth filters if available.